# Android code to change button color on click and back to original color

Tags: android

I want to change the color of button on clicking it and when it is about to move on to next activity its color should be set to original color. In short it should highlight the button clicked by changing the color and back to same color.

Comment: It's expected to show some own effort on solving your problem round here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**mybutton.xml** place this file in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<item android:state_pressed="true" >
 <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
     <corners android:radius="3dip" />
     <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#5e7974" />
     <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#345953" android:endColor="#689a92"  />            
   </shape>
 </item>
<item android:state_focused="true">
 <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
     <corners android:radius="3dip" />
     <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#5e7974" />
     <solid android:color="#58857e"/>       
 </shape>
</item>  
<item >
 <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
     <corners android:radius="3dip" />
     <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#5e7974" />
     <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#8dbab3"  android:endColor="#58857e" />            
  </shape>
 </item>
 </selector>
```

change the colours according to your needs.

Then in your activity xml screen and the following code in place of **Button**

```
<Button
 android:id="@+id/button1"
 android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
 android:layout_width="200dp"
 android:layout_height="126dp" />
```

Answer (score 1):

use button background as in xml :

my_button_selector.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/red"/> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/blue"/> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/black"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Create colors.xml file at res/values folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
     <color name="black">#000</color>
     <color name="blue">#00f</color>
     <color name="red">#f00</color>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

drawable/background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>     
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">   
  <item android:state_pressed="true"   android:drawable= "#000000" />   
  <item android:drawable="#000000" />     
</selector>
```

color/color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>     
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">   
  <item android:state_pressed="true"   android:color= "#000000" />   
  <item android:color="#4b14b1" />     
</selector>
button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background)
button.setTextColor(R.color.color)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set selector of button in your layout file.

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/button1"
     android:background="@drawable/selector_xml_name"
     android:layout_width="200dp"
     android:layout_height="126dp"
     android:text="Hello" />
```

and done.

Edit

Following is button_effect.xml file in drawable directory

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/numpad_button_bg_selected" android:state_selected="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/numpad_button_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/numpad_button_bg_normal"></item>

</selector>
```

In this, you can see that there are 3 drawables, you just need to place this button_effect style to your button, as i wrote above. You just need to replace selector_xml_name with button_effect.

Check out [This](http://angrytools.com/android/button/) link.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a selector in drawable, lots of solutions available.
Follow the below :
1.) Create xml file button_selector in drawable folder :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/numpad_button_bg_selected" android:state_selected="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/numpad_button_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/numpad_button_bg_normal"></item>

</selector>
```

2.) Open you layout and apply this xml selector file on your button:

```
<Button
 android:id="@+id/btnClick"
 android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```